# shell script find and replace in file

Tags: string, shell, design-patterns

I have a file postmaster.log, in which I need to find pattern and change its value
Pattern I need to find is

```
MaxValue=3 #this could be any value not just 3
```

I need to change its value to

```
MaxValue=0
```

Issue is there are also patterns like

```
"MaxValueSet=3" and "MaxValue is currently low"
```

Which are also getting replaced.I only has to change MaxValue=3 to MaxValue=0
I tried using sed

```
 sed -i 's/MaxValue=3/MaxValue=0/g' /home/postmaster.log
```

But this only works if MaxValue=3 for anyother value it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the lines `sed` works on as well:

```
sed -i '/^MaxValue=/s/=[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*/=0/' /home/postmaster.log
```

Comment: I tried and it replaces whole line, I just want to replace MaxValue=3 with MaxValue=0, not the whole line.
This works for whole line replacement though

Comment: I've updated to only replace a positive integer value on the RHS. Other regular expressions can be given to more closely match your usage if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

use a regexp to catch `MaxValue=` followed by any number...

```
s/MaxValue=[0-9]+/MaxValue=0/g
```

should work.

Comment: I tried and it replaces whole line, I just want to replace MaxValue=3 with MaxValue=0, not the whole line.
This works for whole line replacement though

Comment: @JumpOffBox: Are you sure about that? This *should* only replace `MaxValue=` plus one or more digits. Can you give an example where it seems to replace more than that?

Comment: I am sure. I tried and its not working. Example of line from file

     VerifyValue=0         ; VerifyValue should be set to 0
     MaxValue=5            ; Maximum number of Value for kernel jobs

Comment: if I use 

     sed -i "s/MaxValue=.*/MaxValue=0/g", it works but it will replace the whole line not just MaxValue. Are there any other way aprt from sed

Comment: sed -i -r 's/MaxValue=[0-9]+/MaxValue=0/g' /home/postmaster.log

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want

```
sed -i 's/^MaxValue=.*/MaxValue=0/' /home/postmaster.log
```

which will find all lines that begin with `MaxValue=`, and replace each of those lines with `MaxValue=0`.

Comment: As long as the OP wants to replace the **entire** line.

Comment: @jahroy: Yes, absolutely. That's why I always make a point of explaining what the code does, so the OP can judge whether that's actually what (s)he wants.

Comment: I tried and it replaces whole line, I just want to replace MaxValue=3 with MaxValue=0, not the whole line.
This works for whole line replacement though

Comment: @JumpOffBox: Then Jean-Baptiste Yunès' answer is what you want.